# The meaning of 言うなら返しのついていない

Tags: grammar

I was reading 化物語 and came across this paragraph:

> 貫通していないということは、針は、極端に変形していないということだ……ほとんど、コの字形の直角状態を保っているはず。**言うなら返しのついていない**形、ならばそれほどの抵抗なく、力任せに引き抜けるはずだ。

I can understand most of this just fine, but the only part I'm confused about is the meaning 言うなら返しのついていない.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- This 言うなら (or 言わば, 言うならば, 言うなれば) is a phrase meaning "so to speak".
- This 返し refers to a *barb*, the following part of a fishing hook, harpoon, etc:

  [image: 返し]

  When a needle (or hook, stinger) hits a hard object (e.g., a wall), the tip will be crushed and bent like a barb.

So the sentence is saying that since the needle has not fully penetrated and hit something hard, its tip should still be sharp like a barbless fish hook.